# ArrayList of BigIntegers to array of bytes

Tags: c#, arraylist, biginteger

Is it possible to convert an ArrayList of BigIntegers to a byte array? If so, how?

```
 _randomNumbers = new ArrayList(_size);
```

I tried these

```
foreach (BigInteger number in _randomNumbers)
{
    bytes = number.ToByteArray();
}
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok, I'll change it. But it doesn't help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `List<BigInteger>` in the first place. There's no need for an `ArrayList` anymore. Then you can use this LINQ query:

```
var bigIntegers = new List<System.Numerics.BigInteger>(); // fill...
byte[][] allByteArrays = bigIntegers.Select(bi => bi.ToByteArray()).ToArray();
```

Otherwise you need to cast every object in the `ArrayList`:

```
byte[][] allByteArrays = bigIntegersArrayList.Cast<BigInteger>()
    .Select(bi => bi.ToByteArray())
    .ToArray();
```

For the sake of completeness, the classic way without LINQ which can be more efficient:

```
byte[][] allByteArrays = new byte[bigIntegers.Count][];
for (int i = 0; i < allByteArrays.Length; i++)
    allByteArrays[i] = bigIntegers[i].ToByteArray();
```